# tree view in drop down list of report builder

Tags: reporting-services, report, builder

My report needs a drop downlist parameter whose values needs to shown in hierarchial view/parent-child hierarchy.Is it possible in report builder 3.0 ?IF so,can anyone point me in that direction?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to use a tree control for parameters using the out of box report viewer. You could simulate this type of functionality using a [Cascading Parameters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337169(v=sql.100).aspx). Here is a good technet article on how to do this: [How to Add Cascading Parameters to a report](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337169(v=sql.100).aspx).